Next.js. Uncaught Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
Please help me resolve this problem.
I am working on a Project in Next.js and have been facing this error and nothing is helping me resolve it.
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
 ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at ReadyProjectClientPage (./src/components/admin-side/ready-project/ReadyProjectClientPage.js:31:76)
digest: "3449185741"

Here is the ReadyProjectClientPage.js file mentioned in the error:
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { AlertContext } from "@/context/AlertContext";
import { useContext } from "react";
// Other imports

const ReadyProjectClientPage = (props) => {
  const { showAlert } = useContext(AlertContext);
  const addReadyProjectS1Handler = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // addReadyProjectS1Service is a function which runs on the client, checks the input before passing it to the Firebase server action function to add the data to database. No hook is called in this function, however, `showAlert()` returned by the `useContext(AlertContext)` is passed to this function to be called in case of invalid input.
    const data = await addReadyProjectS1Service(
      readyProjectS1,
      showAlert,
      setShowSpinner,
    );
  }
 // showAlert passed to other similar functions as well

  // Other code
  return (
    <>
      {/* JSX */}
    </>
  )
}

The main issue is that I am unable to reproduce the problem. The error appears randomly, once in a few hours, mostly when I reload the page. After it appears, no matter how hard may I try to reproduce it, it would not reappear.
I have manually checked all the hooks and they are all directly inside React components.
Here is my AlertContext.js file:
"use client";
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
const AlertContext = createContext({
  alerts: [],
  showAlert: () => {},
  hideAlert: () => {},
});

const AlertProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([]);

  const showAlert = ({ type, message }) => {
    setAlerts([{ type, message, timestamp: Date.now() }]);
  };

  const hideAlert = () => {
    setAlerts([]);
  };

  return (
    <AlertContext.Provider value={{ alerts, showAlert, hideAlert }}>
      {children}
    </AlertContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AlertProvider, AlertContext };

Here is my root layout.js file in which I have put the AlertProvider:
import { Roboto } from "next/font/google";
import "@/app/globals.css";
import { AlertProvider } from "@/context/AlertContext";
import StoreProvider from "@/store/StoreProvider";

const roboto = Roboto({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["100", "300", "400", "500", "700", "900"],
});

export const metadata = {
  title: "title",
  description: "description",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <StoreProvider>
        <AlertProvider>
          <html lang="en">
            <body className={roboto.className}>{children}</body>
          </html>
        </AlertProvider>
      </StoreProvider>
    </>
  );
}

The versions of react and react-dom are both 18.
I visited the this link to React official site provided in the error description.
Under the Duplicate React section, it says:

If you use Node for package management, you can run this check in your project folder:
npm ls react
If you see more than one React, you’ll need to figure out why this happens and fix your dependency tree.

I ran the command on my terminal and here is the result:
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\project> npm ls react
project@0.1.0 C:\Users\user\Desktop\project
+-- @reduxjs/toolkit@2.2.3
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- next@14.2.1
| +-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| `-- styled-jsx@5.1.1
|   `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- react-dom@18.2.0
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- react-icons@5.1.0
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- react-redux@9.1.1
| +-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| `-- use-sync-external-store@1.2.0
|   `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- react-slick@0.30.2
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
`-- react@18.2.0

Then it says:

You can also try to debug this problem by adding some logs and restarting your development server:

// Add this in node_modules/react-dom/index.js
window.React1 = require('react');

// Add this in your component file
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);

I tried it in my current Next.js project,in a new Next.js project, and in a new React.js project using vite.
I noticed that in any Next.js project, window.React1 pasted in node_modules/react-dom/index.js is not accessible in any component and returns undefined, so console.log(window.React1 === window.React2); always returns false. However in the React project, window.React1 pasted in node_modules/react-dom/index.js is accessible in React components and returns an object.
I have also added react and react-router-dom to peer-dependencies as mentioned in another answer.
{
  "name": "mehraz",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.3",
    "firebase": "^10.11.0",
    "next": "14.2.1",
    "react-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.30.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "ulid": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3"
  }
}


"I have also made it sure that I am not breaking rules of Hooks" I mean no offense, but we are not going to just take your word for that, you need to post the shortest code that demonstrates the problem. It is actually not that easy to wind up with multiple different versions of React on the same page. In over 7 years of writing React, I've seen it happen once, and that was very early on. It is much more likely that you are violating the rules of hooks and don't realize it.

I have now provided additional details along with code in the question.

Again, stop assuming that you know what the problem is. You could be right (as I said it happened to me once in the better part of a decade of writing React) but you're probably wrong, and you're probably violating the rules of hooks in your code. You still have not stripped this down to a minimal reproduction case. What about addReadyProjectS1Service? Because you're not calling that as a hook. If it calls any hooks, that's a violation of the rules of hooks. Why are you importing useRouter? You don't show it being called, are you calling it illegally? etc. etc.

Comment out anything that isn't necessary to reproduce the problem and just show us ALL of the code that isn't commented. In fact, just comment out everything and gradually incrementally re-introduce parts of your app until it breaks. The last thing you uncommented is your problem.

The main issue is that I am unable to reproduce the problem. The error appears randomly, mostly when I reload the page. Now I have been reloading the page in different ways for 5-10 minutes but haven't seen the error yet.

That's cool, I get that it's hard to reproduce, but if we don't have enough code to reproduce it (even if only intermittently) then it will be impossible for us to help you. I get that it's frustrating, those kind of bugs always are :(

You don't have to wrap html and body tag inside your providers, just the children and other layout components that needs your context. It might solve the issue as well.

I am experiencing the same issue. It appears to be a bug in Next.js occurring during development. Unfortunately, since we are unable to reproduce the error, we cannot create an issue on the Next.js GitHub repository. sorry but you just have to trust us when we tell you we are sure that we are not breaking the rules of hooks and we dont know how to reproduce the error

That's unfortunate.
I spent days trying to resolve it, checked every single instance of hooks in my application, posted the issue wherever I could, but none of the solutions worked for me. Now I have just given up.

I had this happen to me and it just needed a Next.js dev server restart to clear up 
In my case the stack trace only had Next.js code in it and not project code.
